# Image component in react native is not able to find images marked as .android.png on Android

Tags: expo, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-image

**Folder Structure**

```
├── app.js
└── assets
    ├── play.android.png
    └── play.ios.png
```

**OR**

```
   ├── app.js
   ├── play.android.png
   └── play.ios.png
```

As per react-native documentation

> The image name is resolved the same way JS modules are resolved. In
> the example above, the bundler will look for my-icon.png in the same
> folder as the component that requires it. Also, if you have
> *my-icon.ios.png* and *my-icon.android.png*, the bundler will pick the
> correct file for the platform.

But when I am trying to load images according to OS. It is showing me error in Android device. In iOS able to load the image.
**Code:-**

```
const App=()=>{
  return (<View>
    <Image source={require("./assets/play.png")} style={{height:500,width:300}}/>
    </View>
  )
}
```

Error:-

> assets/play.png.js (1091:882) Unable to resolve module 'module://assets/play.png.js' (Device) 
> Evaluating module://assets/play.png.js

### **Environment**

**Code**:- Expo Snack@40.0

**Device Tested**:- Redmi Note 8 pro

**Tested in Virtual Android Device embedded with Snack** :-No Error but  Not able to see image.

[image]

**Tested in Virtual iOS Device embedded with Snack** :-Able to see image.

I am able to recreate the scenario in **Expo CLI**
I am not able to launch the same in the above device.

**Error**:-

> Failed building JavaScript bundle. 
> Unable to resolve "./assets/play.png" from "App.js"

Attaching the Screenshot for the same in Mobile.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

here ie the modified solution for your error (https://snack.expo.io/@haryanvidev/experimentals-images)